# I can't use toUpperCase() method on a String parameter, what could be wrong?

Tags: java, string, formatting, concurrenthashmap

I use Eclipse IDE to program for java.
I wrote a class to show whether a name is in a CuncurrentHashMap, my IDE does not show me any error, yet whenever I run my program, I do not get my desired output. My desired output is to have the queries name "Jerry" capitalised. I am only learning the advance principles in java, I am familiar with the basic concepts but I am open to any correction or criticism you have towards my coding style below.

```
package learnJavaPackages;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class AddEmployee {

private String newEmployeeName;
private int empID=0;

ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> hashHandler = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
Scanner inputHere = new Scanner(System.in);


public void AddNewEmployee(){

    System.out.print("Enter a new employee here: " );
    newEmployeeName = inputHere.nextLine();
    
    empID++;
    String empIDstring = Integer.toString(empID);
    
    newEmployeeName = newEmployeeName+empIDstring;
    hashHandler.put(newEmployeeName, empIDstring);
}

public void showAddStatus(){
    System.out.println(newEmployeeName +", has been added to the     company");
}


public void showIsEmployeeIn(String isEmployee) {
    
    isEmployee.toUpperCase();
    
    if(hashHandler.containsKey(isEmployee)){
        System.out.println(isEmployee +" is in the Company.");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(isEmployee +" is not in the company");
    }
}
```

}

**main method:**

```
AddEmployee addEmpRef = new AddEmployee();
    addEmpRef.AddNewEmployee();
    addEmpRef.showAddStatus();
    addEmpRef.showIsEmployeeIn("Jerry");
```

**output:**

```
Enter a new employee here: Isaac
Isaac1, has been added to the company
Jerry is not in the company
```

Comment: Hi @Thilo. Thanks for reviewing this question. With due sincerity I could not find a question similar(duplicate-wise) to mine. Maybe I'm still new to the way things work here, pardon me.

Comment: The link to the duplicate is included in the yellow box right on top of this page, as well as in the "Linked" section on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.toUpperCase()` returns a brand new instance of `String`, which you don't assign to any variable. Just do:

```
isEmployee = isEmployee.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Thank you. This answered my question. I needed to assign the brand new instance of String.

Answer (score 3):

String is immutable. Thus `sEmployee.toUpperCase()` does not change the `sEmployee` object. Instead it returns a new `String`. Use

```
sEmployee = sEmployee.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. As a result, all "mutating" methods return the updated String instead, and you need to pick that up.

```
isEmployee = isEmployee.toUpperCase();
```